# REACTJS - Getting a TypeError for state variable

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, rest, session-state

I'm try to get array data from a web service api (via JSON) and iterate through the response - but when trying to `console.log()` the state data from render(), I get this error:

> TypeError:this.state.jsonStr is undefined.

```
class TextFields extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const apiURL = myConstClass.apiURL;
    var apiURL_ = apiURL + '/searchIdea';

    fetch(apiURL_, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        // SEND 
        idea_uniqueid: '',
        idea_name: '',
        idea_description: '', // FIX: Get from Querystring 
      })
    }).then((Response) => Response.json()).then((findresponse) => {
      // RESPONSE   
      this.setState({ jsonStr: findresponse, });
      console.log("SEARCHIDEARESULTS"); // Stopped here - Loop through array and populate below
      console.log(this.state.jsonStr);

    })
  }


  // RENDER
  // ---------------------------------------------------------------

  render() {

    const { classes } = this.props;
    const dataStr = this.state.jsonStr;
    console.log("RENDER"); // Stopped here - Loop through array and populate below
    console.log(this.state.jsonStr);
    console.log(this.state.jsonStr[0]);

    return (
      <div></div>
    )

  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for the `setState` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because when the component is rendered for the first time the promise returned by fetch has not yet been resolved so the `jsonStr` is not found in the state. to fix this add jsonStr to the initial state and assign a value to it

```
TextFields extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
         jsonStr: ''
      }
    }
}
```

or else you could also add conditions to check whether the jsonStr is set

```
TextFields extends React.Component {

 constructor() {
     super();
     this.state = {
       jsonStr: undefined
     }
 }

 render() {

        const { classes } = this.props;
        const dataStr = this.state.jsonStr;
        console.log("RENDER");
        if (this.state.jsonStr) {
            console.log(this.state.jsonStr);
            console.log(this.state.jsonStr[0]);
        }
        return (
          <div></div>
        )

      }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Initially `this.state.jsonStr` will be undefined. So when executing `render()` method `this.state.jsonStr[0]` will throw error.

Try changing `console.log(this.state.jsonStr[0]);` to `console.log(this.state.jsonStr && this.state.jsonStr[0]);`

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers touch on `default` state values or the error in `render`. But I see another error in your data fetching function.

From [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#why-is-setstate-giving-me-the-wrong-value):

> Calls to setState are asynchronous - don’t rely on this.state to reflect the new value immediately after calling setState.

In your `componentDidMount` method, you are making that mistake:

```
this.setState({ jsonStr: findresponse, });
console.log("SEARCHIDEARESULTS"); // Stopped here - Loop through array and populate below
console.log(this.state.jsonStr);
```

If you want to debug, I highly recommend the devTools extension, or put your console.log statements either as a callback to setState or in `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle.

Few notes on the advice for your render method, Do think of what your component states can be. For e.x. if fetching data from an external service, you may have the following states:

- Loading
- Error
- No Data Found
- Data Found

When you do: `const dataStr = this.state.jsonStr ? this.state.jsonStr : ""`, you may lose the possibility to distinguish between these states.

I would advice to make that state state explicit (there are many techniques out there, I am leaving them out for brevity), but at the least I would suggest intelligent defaults. For e.x.:

```
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
       jsonStr : undefined
    }
  };
```

Your api call will either return value, null or an empty Array (if it is an array). May also throw an error, which you can catch with `componentDidCatch`.

You can now handle these cases in your render method easily.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to access to `this.state.jsonStr` before you define it and as a result you get the error:

> TypeError:this.state.jsonStr is undefined.

Try setting it in the constructor:

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      jsonStr: ''
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this  modified code:

```
render() {

    const { classes } = this.props;
    const dataStr = this.state.jsonStr ? this.state.jsonStr : ""  ;// I made a change here
    console.log("RENDER"); // Stopped here - Loop through array and populate below
    console.log(dataStr);


    return (
      <div></div>
    )

  }
}
```

Comment: Great this works. I am now able to view the array via console.log(dataStr[0]) , but when I try to view the element (dataStr[0].lkpEmail), I get the same errror - TypeError: dataStr[0] is undefine. But at least the fix is step forward, thanks!!

Comment: When you fetch data from network it is recommended to check whether data exists. Like we did above. Try to apply the same practice to the code above for which you get error:    console.log(dataStr[0].lkpEmail ? dataStr[0].lkpEmail : "" )